# How to resolve Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, undefined

I am completely new to react.js. This is a first project on react and I am just following the YouTube tutorials to create a covid-19 tracker application. I have build many components. I have to display a chart for that I have created chart.jsx file.

I am getting an unexpected error and I cannot resolve it but the tutor does not get that error in tutorial. The error is

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

When i tried to remove **.length** from my code, the application started running again but i was unable to display chart.  I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am leaving the code below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khJlrj3Y6Ls&t=2279s At **56:00**

you can see it in tutorial at 56:00

I am getting the list errors and I know I am just making a silly mistake but I am not getting it. I thing some thing is wrong with particularly with the lines of code in the firs error.
[image]

CODE:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { fetchDailyData } from '../../api';
import { Line, Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

import styles from './Chart.module.css';

const Chart =() => {
    const [dailyData, setDailyData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() =>{
        const fetchAPI = async () => {
            setDailyData(await fetchDailyData()); 
        }

        fetchAPI();
    });

    const lineChart = (
        dailyData.length
        ? (
        <lineChart
            data={{
                labels: dailyData.map(({ date }) => date),
                datasets: [{
                        data: dailyData.map(({ confirmed }) => confirmed ),
                        label: 'Infected',
                        borderColor: '#3333ff',
                        fill: true,
                }, {
                    data: dailyData.map(({ deaths }) => deaths ),
                    label: 'Deaths',
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
                    fill: true,
                }],
            }}
        />
        ) : null
    )

    return( 
        <div className={styles.container}>
            {lineChart}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Chart;
```

Comment: what does your `fetchDailyData` return? Cause `dailyData` would be initialized with an empty array at the start, but you are setting it inside the async function inside `useEffect`

Comment: Yes, please add your code for `fetchDailyData()`.

Answer (score 0):

check your index.js within the projects api folder & make sure you're using a backtick (`) instead of single quotes (') within your url statement.